# Count hits for post using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How i can develop a hit counter for my posts.

I have a mysql table with following cols

id   title   body  hits

how i can increment hits by 1 whenever a user read post entry.

Please help.

Comment: Look at this question.Make it clear man...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the page where you show your post you should update database.

I.e. you show post `post.php?id=53` so in `post.php` you have to do

```
'UPDATE table SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id = ' . (int) $_GET['id']
```